# How -s option works actually in gcc compilers?

Tags: gcc, g++, command-line-interface

`gcc` & `g++` provides command line option **`-s`** to reduce the size of executable file. But I want to know that how this **`-s`** option works exactly? What it does so that size of the executable reduces? How the size of file gets reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux systems, `gcc -s` probably invokes the [strip(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strip.1.html) utility (which remove most symbols from [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files) from [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/). You could check by running `gcc -v -s`.

To lower the executable size, you should also compile with `-Os` (in addition of `-s`) which asks the compiler to optimize for size.

Comment: What is this ELF file?

Comment: ELF is the format of binary executables and of object files on Linux